# ParentId field is not visible on Note sobject

Tags: apex, visualforce, notes

> ERROR: variable ParentID does not Exist
>    on running the following lines

```
Note n = new Note();
try {               
    n.ParentId='a017F0000015hib';
    n.Body=note;
    n.Title='New Note';
    insert n;
```

Comment: check FLS for runnning user

Comment: Do you have a custom class declared named `Note`?

Answer (score 1):

You usually see this sort of error when you introduce a naming collision by creating a custom class which shares its name with a standard object/class. You can make sure you are creating an `SObject` instead of an instance of the custom class by prepending `Schema.` to your type:

```
Schema.Note n = new Schema.Note();
```

Comment: What is this Schema, i didn't undestand...will please tell me